# Donkeycar simulator connection - macOS error (loggerinfo)

Tags: python, macos

I tried to link donkeycar gym to donkey-sim, but when I go to the directory with cd command and execute python manage.py drive , than it returns the following error:

```
  File "manage.py", line 48
    logger.info(f'PID: {os.getpid()}')
```

I didn't touch manage.py file, and how can I fix it?

- Here is the code of manage.py. (before line 32: they are imports and notes.)

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


def drive(cfg, model_path=None, use_joystick=False, model_type=None,
          camera_type='single', meta=[]):
    """
    Construct a working robotic vehicle from many parts. Each part runs as a
    job in the Vehicle loop, calling either it's run or run_threaded method
    depending on the constructor flag `threaded`. All parts are updated one
    after another at the framerate given in cfg.DRIVE_LOOP_HZ assuming each
    part finishes processing in a timely manner. Parts may have named outputs
    and inputs. The framework handles passing named outputs to parts
    requesting the same named input.
    """
    logger.info(f'PID: {os.getpid()}')
    if cfg.DONKEY_GYM:
        #the simulator will use cuda and then we usually run out of resources
        #if we also try to use cuda. so disable for donkey_gym.
        os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by using anaconda.